# Can I listen to multiple caches using same com.tangosol.util.MapListener instance?

Tags: oracle-coherence

Can I listen to multiple Coherence Caches using a single `com.tangosol.util.MapListener` instance? As can be seen in the below code snippet, I have created an instance of `MapListener` and using the same instance to listen to multiple coherence caches. My concern is that would this piece of code work in case of multiple Events being generated from both the caches?

```java
protected class MapListenerImpl implements MapListener {

    @Override
    public void entryDeleted(MapEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Delete Event: " + event.getOldEntry());
    }

    @Override
    public void entryInserted(MapEvent event) {
        System.out.println("INsert Event: " + event.getNewEntry());

    }

    @Override
    public void entryUpdated(MapEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Update Event: " + event.getNewEntry());

    }       
}

//Main Method
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Initializing the caches here
    NamedCache mapTrades1;
    NamedCache mapTrades2;

    MapListener listener = new MapListenerImpl();

    mapTrades1.addMapListener(listener);
    mapTrades2.addMapListener(listener);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, but it might be challenging to determine to which map an event corresponds.  If you need to keep the events separate but you need to keep shared state, I would suggest creating separate listener objects but have them both hold a reference to a single shared state object.

Comment: Hello Brett. Hope you are doing well. 
Do you know if we can implement a timeout functionality with com.tangosol.util.MapListener? Do we need to set an external timer mechanism for this or is there a way for us to do that using MapListener?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used the product in too long and no longer remember those kinds of details.  I suggest opening another question.